# Laravel logging to to custom channel does not consider minimum level

Tags: laravel, logging, levels

So i made a custom logging handler with a custom logger to log to db, and it works correctly.

What i cannot manage to work is the minimum loggin level define in the configuration.
To test it i made a stack with `single` and my custom channel (let's call it `database`), hanving both a `error` level, and logged a message for every log level with artisan: the daily file contains 4 messages, but my custom channel has 8 messages while i expected only 4.

Testing with a stack of `single` and `daily` instead work correctly, so this makes me think that i have to handle the minimum loggin level in my custom classes, but i couldn't find anywhere something that tells it explicitly.

Is not a problem to update my custom classes to check the log level, but i want to be sure that i'm not mistaking something else about laravel logging.

#### config/logging.php

```php
    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single', 'daily'],
            //'channels' => ['single', 'database'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'error',
        ],
        'database' => [
            'driver'    => 'custom',
            'handler'   => App\Logging\CustomLoggingHandler::class,
            'via'       => App\Logging\CustomLogger::class,
            'level'     => env('MIN_DB_LOGGING_LEVEL', 'error'),
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Laravel supports 7 different log levels: `emergency`, `alert`, `critical`, `error`, `warning`, `notice`, `info`, and `debug`. If you need less messages than returned by `error`, try changng to, for instance, `emergency` or `critical`.

Comment: The point here is that if i set my custom channel `level => 'error'` it still log even `debug` messages, like laravel is ignoring the `level` value in the configuration; i just want to know if i'm missing something about laravel log handling or if i need to check the log level in my custom classes.

Comment: @KazikM moreover, laravel support 8 logging levels, you missed `critical`

Comment: You are right, I wrote "7" and listed all 8 of them.

Comment: Your `database` channel gets its value ftom env:  `env('MIN_DB_LOGGING_LEVEL', 'error')`. Maybe the problem is there. Check `MIN_DB_LOGGING_LEVEL` value in .env file.

Comment: @KazikM i had no value in the `.env`, it is just to enable further customization. For now, i just solved checking the level in my custom classes. Maybe it is the same for existing loggers, nonetheless the config parmas are passed to the logger class.